# <IMG> does not stay inline - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few selects and a `<img>` and I make all the elements in javascript as there only get added on a button click that is separate and does not affect the code below, as I have tried with and without and I get the same result. Here is the html, css and Javascript I also have included as [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jizeyulehu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) as it clearly shows the issue, currently I have tested on Chrome and IE, and it works fine on Chrome but breaks on IE 11.0.96, what happens is I have a `select` then `img` then `select` and I want the `img` to be beside the first select and have the next `select` below, like this

[image]

But on IE the button goes over top of the second `select`

Here code

```
<body>
  <div id="hours_div"></div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#info_add_hours {
  width: 50%;
}

.time_p {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.time_colon {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;

}

#hours_div select {

  width: 88%;
}

#time_delete_small {
    width:40px;
    display:inline;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;

}

#hours_div .time_select {
    width:23%;
}


#hours_div .ampm_select {
    margin-left:5px;
    width:23%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function el(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
} // Get elem by ID


var numOfHours = 0;

var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var div_id = "div_hours_" + numOfHours;
div.id = div_id;

//WEEKDAY
var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
var option_mon = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_mon.value = "monday";
var monday = document.createTextNode("Monday");
var option_tue = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_tue.value = "tuesday";
var tuesday = document.createTextNode("Tuesday");
var option_wed = document.createElement("OPTION");

option_mon.appendChild(monday);
option_tue.appendChild(tuesday);

select.appendChild(option_mon);
select.appendChild(option_tue);


//OPEN HOUR
var select_hour_open = document.createElement("SELECT");
select_hour_open.className = 'time_select';
var option_1_open = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_1_open.value = "1";
var option_1_text_open = document.createTextNode("1");
option_1_open.appendChild(option_1_text_open);
var option_2_open = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_2_open.value = "2";
var option_2_text_open = document.createTextNode("2");
option_2_open.appendChild(option_2_text_open);

select_hour_open.appendChild(option_1_open);
select_hour_open.appendChild(option_2_open);


var p_to = document.createElement("P");
p_to.className = 'time_p';
var to_text = document.createTextNode("to");
p_to.appendChild(to_text);




var close_img = document.createElement("IMG");
close_img.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/2338/reflection/128/button_delete.png';
close_img.id = 'time_delete_small';



div.appendChild(select);
div.appendChild(close_img);

div.appendChild(select_hour_open);



div.appendChild(p_to);



el("hours_div").appendChild(div);
```

So why is the button going over top of the 2nd select?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know the cause of the bug, but you could just wrap all of the elements in a div and make the image position: absolute. Put some padding on the right side of the div to keep the other elements off it.

Comment: @RickyGoldman I have all the elements in a div and I have the `position:absolute` for the image

Comment: @spenf10 your time_delete_small  element has a problem rules it has a inline but it is position absolute.... This is not quite well remove the absolute or remove the inline. Also one of your problems is that you do not have top right or whatever position you need.

Answer (score 2):

The difference seems to be arising because IE is positioning the IMG element as a block element with respect to its containing block (DIV #div_hours_0), whereas Firefox ( at least) looks to be positioning the IMG element with respect to where it would have appeared inline without positioning. (I don't know offhand if this agrees with standards or not.)

Changing display to block and adding "left" and "margin-top" rules:

```
#time_delete_small {
    width:40px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    left: 88%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

seems to create the layout shown in the post as the correct one. By all means experiment and tweak them for your purposes!

Comment: but setting it to block it no longer works if you change the screen size

Comment: works for me in IE and Firefox. what happens in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

For IE 11.0.96 U need to change settings Go to tools -> compatibility view setting ->click on add button and it will now compatible to IE